# Distance between elements debugging

Tags: debugging, matlab

I'm having a silly error when calculating the distance between pixels in the y direction, but not the x direction. this should make it clearer:

```
% Distance matrix
for pxRow = 1:h % fixed pixel row
  for pxCol = 1:w % fixed pixel column   

    for r = 1:h % row of distant pixel
      for c = 1:w % column of distant pixel

        Rx(c,r) = sqrt((r-pxRow)^2);   % get distance to each pixel x direction
        Ry(c,r) = sqrt((c-pxCol)^2);   % get distance to each pixel y direction

      end
    end

    Rix(i) = {Rnx};
    Riy(i) = {Rny};
    i = i+1;
  end
end

Rix = reshape(Rix, w, h);
Riy = reshape(Riy, w, h);
```

where

```
Rix = 

NaN   1.000   0.500   0.333
NaN   1.000   0.500   0.333 
NaN   1.000   0.500   0.333
```

which is correct, but

```
Riy = 

NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000 
1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000
```

which is incorrect, as I want Riy to just be a rotation of Rix.

Where is the error here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's quite difficult to see what you are really trying to achieve. Consider adding either an explanatory image of what you are attempting to do or detail a bit more what are those `Rx`, `Ry`, `Rnx` and `Rny`

Comment: I don't think that you pasted your code correctly.  `Rnx` and `Rny` are not set anywhere in the for loop.  Do you mean `Rx` and `Ry`, or did you leave some lines out?

Comment: @sfstewman ^^^ yes you're right! it should be Rx Ry (i must have been in the middle of debugging). This has been solved now.